# Telnet Using C# Console Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, telnet

I have a Server which i can telnet to it using my Windows 7. i just type telnet then open host port in Cmd and then my username and password . after it every thing will be ok and i can execute all my commands, I want to know, Is there any way like this in C# ? Just Connect to Host port pass the Username and Password , and just executing commands?

Comment: do you search on internet first ? here one: http://www.activexperts.com/activsocket/howto/telnet/aspnetc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Minimalistic Telnet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19071/Quick-tool-A-minimalistic-Telnet-library), which is a good, free C# telnet client library.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of whatever deity you are worshiping...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet

There is no wire protocol for Telnet... it's in the bits and you don't really have to worry about that unless you are doing something advanced (which you are not)

1) Use a TcpClient, Connect on the port (possibly 23) 
2) Use the Encoding.GetBytes('commmand') to create a command.
3) Send the bytes on the Socket and process the response...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Process.Start to start the telnet process, and then send data to the standard input of that process, and reading from the standard out.

Comment: sorry if i want it in Asp.net that i can Send my commands from website is it possible?